# Surprise changing of Terminal background

Tags: terminal, settings, color

I was doing various things with Terminal but at one point, without typing anything, the background behind the text changed from white to pink.  No settings windows (nor any other window) had appeared.

I'm aware that there are [commands available](https://superuser.com/questions/268440/how-can-i-change-the-terminal-console-color-in-osx-without-opening-a-new-console) to do this, but I had not typed anything when it happened.  (And none of the commands I've ever typed have changed the color.)

**What might cause this?**

(I don't think it's related, but I have [another irritation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470773/unwanted-man-page-widget) happening recently.)

Comment: What happened afterwards? Did the colour switch back to white?

Comment: I wasn't aware of how to change it back.  Tried changing focus to another window and back.  Didn't help, so I exited Terminal and launched another, which came up in the normal black on white.

Comment: Edit background color

Option-Command-I

Comment: Yes, that works.  But it's not possible for me to do that without knowing it!